# Julia installation on Mac Pro fails

Tags: julia, osx-elcapitan

I am using Mac Pro with El Capitan. I tried installing Julia through homebrew but it fails with the following stack trace

```
==> make FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
Last 15 lines from /Users/vishalsharma/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openblas-julia/01.make:
printf("#define DLOCAL_BUFFER_SIZE\t%ld\n", (DGEMM_DEFAULT_Q *  DGEMM_DEFAULT_UNROLL_N * 2 * 1 *  sizeof(double)));
                                                               ^
getarch_2nd.c:69:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGEMM_DEFAULT_Q'
printf("#define CLOCAL_BUFFER_SIZE\t%ld\n", (CGEMM_DEFAULT_Q * CGEMM_DEFAULT_UNROLL_N * 4 * 2 *  sizeof(float)));
                                             ^
getarch_2nd.c:69:68: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGEMM_DEFAULT_UNROLL_N'
printf("#define CLOCAL_BUFFER_SIZE\t%ld\n", (CGEMM_DEFAULT_Q * CGEMM_DEFAULT_UNROLL_N * 4 * 2 *  sizeof(float)));
                                                               ^
getarch_2nd.c:70:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ZGEMM_DEFAULT_Q'
printf("#define ZLOCAL_BUFFER_SIZE\t%ld\n", (ZGEMM_DEFAULT_Q * ZGEMM_DEFAULT_UNROLL_N * 2 * 2 *  sizeof(double)));
                                             ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [getarch_2nd] Error 1
Makefile:131: *** OpenBLAS: Detecting CPU failed. Please set TARGET  explicitly, e.g. make TARGET=your_cpu_target. Please read README for the detail..  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `OpenBLAS` can't detect your CPU architecture. Do you have a Nehalem CPU? You'll need to create a `Make.inc` file with `OPENBLAS_TARGET_ARCH=NEHALEM` inside it, and run `make TARGET=NEHALEM FC=...` or similar (adjust `NEHALEM` to `HASWELL` or your arch as appropriate). See the recent comments on [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/370) GitHub issue.